# what is difference between using as operator for casting IEnumerable to Array and using ToArray extension method of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, resharper, ienumerable

Let's say we have a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>` and we want to cast it into an array.
Resharper has suggested my a snippet like this:

```
var collection = input as T[] ?? input.ToArray()
```

Is there any chance in which `input as T[]` returns `null` so that the `input.ToArray()` part comes to action? Even if that occurs, why wouldn't we directly use the extension method instead of that? like this:

```
var collection = input.ToArray();
```

What is the difference between casting through calling `ToArray` extension method and using `as` operator?

Comment: `input` may be `null` itself, and `input.ToArray()` fails

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) operator.

Comment: input = new List<T>(); Assert.IsNull(input as T[]);

Comment: `input` can be `List<T>`, or it can be an output of enumerator function, or it can be any other non-array implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`. In that case **new** array is created (it's not casting). Otherwise, you just get original array which was passed as `IEnumerable<T>` (casting)